# Will Paginate + Rails with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination

I'm having a problem where `pagination` works properly in displaying the correct number of pages to display all objects, but it's simply repeating all of the same objects on each page.  (eg. If there are 10 objects and my `per_page` is 10, it'll show one page and all 10 items; if `per_page` is 5, it'll show 2 pages, but in both cases it keeps repeating ALL of objects from 1-10 on every page)

There is a HMBTM relationship, and all `images` associated in this case with the `product` model is in a join model.

I'm using this pagination gem: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

```
Products Controller
    def show
        @products = @product.images.all.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
      end
```

View

```
 <% @product.images.each_slice(2) do |f,g| %>
...
<% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @products %>
```

Comment: try this  @product.images.page(params[:page]).per_page(10)

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Thanks for that.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: can you shoe me the association

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already defined `@products` in the controller so I had to adjust my view so it didn't repeat the same code and just used the defined instance variable.

```
 <% @products.each_slice(2) do |f,g| %>
...
<% end %>
  <%= will_paginate @products %>
```